# How to create a dropdown box as shown below in html5 and css3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to Create an drop down menu as shown in screen shot

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrEnR.jpg)

Comment: Have you attempted to implement this? If so, can you show your code so you can get some further guidance?

Comment: Enclosing the screenshot of the code

Comment: <div id="container">
 <div class="sidebar">
   <ul id="nav">
              
            <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
       
       <ul>

            <li><a href="">UX design</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">IOS</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">Android</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CS</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Xarmarain</a></li>
       </li>
       </ul>

Answer (score 0):

After visiting their site, it seem that they are using jquery .click() to control the classes and visibility of the element. So for example, you would do

```
$('#click_this').click(function(){
    $('#dropdown_menu').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Comment: <div id="header">
   <img alt="a" src="images/a.png">
 </div>
 <a class="mobile" href="#">
  Menu
 </a>

 <div id="container">
 <div class="sidebar">
   <ul id="nav">
              
            <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
       
       <ul>

            <li><a href="">UX design</a></li>
                  <li><a href="">IOS</a></li>
                   <li><a href="">Android</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">CS</a></li>
                      <li><a href="">Xarmarain</a></li>
       </li>
       </ul>

Comment: It seems that you don't know HTML yet. Learn HTML before anything please. Best of luck.